# Makefile w. Protocol Buffer and Automatic Dependency

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers

I have a Makefile something like this:

```
.SECONDARY:

NVCC = nvcc
NVCCFLAGS = --gpu-architecture compute_20

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -std=c++0x -Wall

CXXLINT = python cpplint.py
CXXLINTFLAGS = --filter=-build/include,-readability/streams,-runtime/sizeof,-whitespace/parens

PROTOC = protoc
PROTOCFLAGS = --cpp_out=.

BINS = my_binary
LIBS = -lcublas -lcusparse
PROTOS = $(wildcard *.proto)
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cu)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.cuh)
PBS = $(PROTOS:%.proto=%.pb)
DEPS = $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.d)
TESTS = my_test

all: lint protos
all: deps
all: bins
protos: ${PBS}
deps: ${DEPS}
bins: ${BINS}

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.d *.pb.cc *.pb.h ${BINS} ${TESTS}

lint:
    ${CXXLINT} ${CXXLINTFLAGS} ${SOURCES}
    ${CXXLINT} ${CXXLINTFLAGS} ${HEADERS}

tests: lint protos
tests: deps
tests: ${TESTS}
tests: tests-run
tests-run: ${TESTS}
    for f in $^; do eval "/usr/bin/time -f \"$$f runtime: %E\" ./$$f"; done

%: %.o
    ${NVCC} ${NVCCFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LIBS}

%.d: %.cu
#   ${CXXLINT} ${CXXLINTFLAGS} $*.cu
    ${NVCC} -M -o $*.d $*.cu

%.o: %.cu
    ${NVCC} ${NVCCFLAGS} -c -o $@ $*.cu
    rm $*.d

%.pb: %.proto
    ${PROTOC} ${PROTOCFLAGS} $*.proto
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c -o $*.pb.o $*.pb.cc

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include ${DEPS}
endif
```

The problem occurs since I can not generate my DEPS until my proto target is built. Because building the protocol buffers will add a new header file to the tree, if this isn't done first before the DEPS, the nvcc -M (make dependency) will fail since it can not find the *.pb.h that is generated. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `protoc`; is the name of the generated header file known beforehand? That is, if you `make foo.pb`, will it generate `foo.pb.h`, or might it produce `bar.pb.h`?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to make your dependency files depend on the results of the protocol buffer generation. The following snippet contains all steps to do that, since it is hard to explain them one by one, with an explanation of some items at the bottom:

```
CXX_FLAGS      := $(shell pkg-config --cflags protobuf) -xc++
LD_FLAGS       := $(shell pkg-config --libs protobuf)

PROTOS         := $(wildcard *.proto)
PROTO_OBJS     := $(PROTOS:.proto=.pb.o)

BINS     := my_binary

SRCS     := $(wildcard *.cu)
OBJS     := $(SRCS:.cu=.o)
DEPS     := $(SRCS:.cu=.d)

PBSRCS   := $(wildcard *.proto)
PBOBJS   := $(PROTOS:.proto=.pb.o)
PBGENS   := $(PROTOS:.proto=.pb.cc) $(PROTOS:.proto=.pb.h)

all: $(BINS)

clean:
        rm -f $(BINS) $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(PBOBJS) $(PBGENS)

$(BINS): $(OBJS)
$(OBJS): $(DEPS)
$(DEPS): $(PBOBJS)

.PRECIOUS: $(PBGENS)

%.d: %.cu
        $(CXX) -M $(CXX_FLAGS) $< > $@

%.pb.cc: %.proto
        protoc --cpp_out=. $<

%.pb.o : %.pb.cc
        $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cu
        $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINS): %: %.o
        $(CXX) $(LD_FLAGS) -o $@ $(PROTO_OBJS) $^

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

The `pkg-config` command is not required, but is convenient if you want to automatically obtain compilation and linking flags relevant for the protobuf files. Of course, you have to add your own flags to this variable.

The `-xc++` is probably useless for you, but used here in order to be able to work with `.cu` files and have them interpreted as C++; even for compilers different than `nvcc`.

The line `$(DEPS): $(PBOBJS)` is the indication that the protobuf files should be created and compiled before the dependencies are created. There a several ways to achieve this, so this is just an example of how to do it.

The `.PRECIOUS` line instructs `make` to keep the generated protobuf files. In this example snippet, those files are considered intermediate and as such would be deleted without this line.

I posted this as a separate answer, because the previous one and this one do not have much in common.

Comment: I'm working on getting this to work myself. I find makefiles strangely baffling for some reason, so I have a question. What's the reason behind having `PROTOS := $(wildcard *.proto)` and `PBSRCS := $(wildcard *.proto)`. This seems unnecessary - or am I missing something.

Comment: @SeanLynch You are correct, `PBSRCS` is not necessary. Additionally, `PROTO_OBJS` and `PBOBJS` are duplicates, but I did that on purpose to distinguish between variables used for dependency purposes versus variables used as part of the build commands. I will clean it up a little bit later. And `make` is baffling, not just for you, so not strangely :-) . What problem do you run into?

Comment: Thanks. I'm having an issue with dependencies and the fact that the sources for the project are separated in a hierarchy of subdirectories underneath the directory that has the Makefile

Comment: @SeanLynch Do you get this to work at all if you test it in a flat directory structure (just to make sure that the basic dependencies work for you)? After that, you could take the next step by moving back to your own directory structure and use make debug/print flags to debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When building the dependencies, you could opt to continue even if header files are missing. Using `cpp` or `gcc`, that can be achieved by using the options `-MM -MG`. I have no experience with NVCC, but I did not see any support those flags in the manual. If that is true, then you could try switching to `cpp` for the dependency generation only. From the `cpp` man page:

> -MG assumes missing header files are generated files and adds them to the dependency list without raising an error.

Your pattern rule `%.pb: %.proto` does not seem right to me, by the way. It is `%.pb.h` and `%.pb.cc` that depend on `%.proto` and with the current approach, `make` will not know how to resolve any dependencies on `%.pb.h` because it will not know how to create the `.pb.h` file.

Comment: The problem w. using GCC for dependency generation is that it might get confused w. the CUDA code? i.e. CUDA kernels and the CUDA syntax?

Comment: What do you suggest for the pattern rule for the protocol buffers then? Thanks.

Comment: No, `cpp` should have no problem with your CUDA code. Did you try it? See my answer below for a different approach.